# 'Undefined Offset 1' error

Tags: php, parsing

```
<?php 

require "connect.php";

$file = "./myFile2.txt";
$document = file_get_contents($file);

$lines = explode("\n",$document);

foreach($lines as $newline) {

   $arr = explode('Order Number: ', $newline);
    $important = $arr[1]; //getting an error here (undefined offset 1)

    echo $important;

    $art = explode('Total Price: ', $newline);
    $first = $art[1]; //getting an error here (undefined offset 1)

    echo $first; 

}

?>
```

myFile2.txt reads as follows:

```
Order Number: 12345
Total price: 60$
```

The code outputs both '12345' and '60$' yet displays an 'Undefined Offset: 1' after each echo.

How can i fix this? Do i have to account for the return key that separates order number and total price?

Comment: What does `var_dump($important);` print?

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with SQL so I removed the tag.

Comment: string(6) "12345 " and 60$NULL

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: did u catch my last comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exploding `Order Number: 12345` as :- `explode('Order Number: ', $newline);` and therefore your required value is in the `0` offset of your array.

If you had exploded in this way :-

```
explode(':', $string); //$string = Order Number:12345
```

Then you would not get the error.

So try replacing :-

```
$important = $arr[1];
```

with

```
$important = $arr[0];
```

Comment: problem is that i need 'Total Price' and 'Order Number' omitted in the echo. So what I'm echoing is actually '12345' and '60$'

Comment: Then do `$array = explode(':', $string); //$string = Order Number:12345` and echo `$array[1]`. This will produce output as 12345.

Comment: Awesome, it worked! Though any idea why it's echoing the result twice?

Comment: @T888 
Because you have a foreach loop, which runs twice.
If you found my answer useful, please tick it as accepted.

Comment: @T888
No issues, have a great day programming :)

Comment: okay, I'm sorry to bring you back to this, but how can i avoid having the result echo twice?

Comment: Don't use the foreach loop. For Order number, use :- `$arr = explode(':', $lines[0]);`